# Forwarding traffic between 2 interfaces

Tags: iptables, routing

I have 2 VLANs connected to a 'router'. All the machines can ping other machines within their own VLAN and the router. The router can ping all of the machines. I am trying to get machines to talk to other VLAN via the router.

On the router, the VLANs are on eth1 and eth2. I have added the following iptable rules:

```
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth2 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

On machines within the VLANs I added the following route entry:

```
route add -net 172.16.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.16.30.1
```

Where `172.16.0.X` is the ip address range in the other VLAN and `172.16.30.1` is the router's IP.

What did I do wrong? What did I not do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Worked when I did:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
```