# Route specific program to specific NIC

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager

I have two internet connection, One internet connection has very high latency, it has fluctuation in connection (there is a tree between tower & Wifi CPE, so signal goes up & down) but its fine for downloading as connection never goes to 0. Another one is landline connection, they have strong download limit.

So what i want is to use wlan0 for few specific programs like, steam & downloading etc. basically program which consume lot of data.

And i want to use wlan1 for browsing & other stuffs, less data.

**In short, I want to route specific programs though specific NIC, I don't have specific range of IP's.**

I can connect both of them through wifi as i have 1 extra wifi adapter (wlan0,wlan1), as another option i can connect one with ethernet (wlan0,eth0)

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible if your process has something [`iptables`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/iptables.8) can match against, such as a specific group. For example, given a group `to-wifi`, you could have iptables rules like so:

```
iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface wlan0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner to-wifi --out-interface wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

(And with forwarding enabled: `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1`.)

Then, if you run, for example, Steam thus:

```
sg to-wifi steam
```

Any traffic from that Steam process (+ any child processes) will be forwarded from whichever interface it was heading through to the wireless interface.

I have never tried interface-to-interface redirection, but I have used `iptables` to redirect all TCP traffic from Steam to a proxy by matching against groups, so these rules may not be enough by themselves.

---

This could be accomplished by creating groups for each interface and adding yourself to them. For example, using the [`addgroup` and `adduser`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/adduser.8) commands:

```
sudo addgroup to-wifi
sudo adduser $USER to-wifi
sudo addgroup for-eth0
sudo adduser $USER for-eth0
```

You need to re-login for your new group memberships to take effect.

Related:

- [Forwarding traffic between 2 interfaces](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338100/forwarding-traffic-between-2-interfaces)
- [iptables forward all traffic to interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126595/iptables-forward-all-traffic-to-interface)
- [iptables forwarding between two interfaces](https://serverfault.com/questions/431593/iptables-forwarding-between-two-interface)
- [How to forward packets between two interfaces?](https://superuser.com/questions/684275/how-to-forward-packets-between-two-interfaces)

Comment: I am newbie, so can you please explain which type of group ? user account group, sudo,user etc ? How can i create a group ?

Comment: Any group will do. I have added the commands for creating groups.

Comment: ok. So basically i will be adding my user to two groups, then will run process with specific group using sg ? Correct ?

Comment: I am getting error `iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.`, i created group named `to-wlan0` & `to-eth0`, then ran `iptables -t nat -A output -m owner --gid-owner to-wlan0 --out-interface wlan0 -j MASQUERADE  `

Comment: The `output` is supposed to be `OUTPUT` (all caps), sorry about that. Yes, you will be adding yourself to two groups, and `sg` is for running the command as a specific group (equivalent to `sudo`).

Comment: again error :( `iptables: Invalid argument. Run `dmesg' for more information.`, dmesg response last few line `[11288.055152] hub 2-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 7
[11694.264460] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max)
[13081.375763] x_tables: ip_tables: MASQUERADE target: used from hooks OUTPUT, but only usable from POSTROUTING`

Comment: i changed command to `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m owner --gid-owner to-wifi --out-interface wlan0 -j MASQUERADE` but still its not working

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do that.

This can be done with iptables rules on the specific *ports* + destinations they use to make their connections, but I'm not aware of a local way to do it.